# NMTOKEN questions. Am I overthinking it?

Tags: xml, debugging, dtd

I have another quick question regarding my XML assignment.

1) The assignment states that I need to add a  NMTOKEN to my code. Do I simply input the code as `<!ATTLIST catalog type NMTOKEN #REQUIRED>`? Or should I actually put a name for it? There was a very short section on NMTOKEN and NMTOKENS that didn't exactly state if I needed to make it or not.

The instruction is `The type attribute, a required attribute of the catalog element, containing a valid XML name`

The only code in the file I was given that would fit this instruction is `<catalog type="photos">`

2)The second question is very similar to the first in which it states to use NMTOKENS. Would I simply make a similar code as shown above but with NMTOKENS in place? There are multiple code that have the similar element `metadata`. So would I just repeat the code until I have made a string for each metadata?

The question is `The metadata attribute, a required attribute of the name element, containing a list of valid XML names`

The codes that would fit the instructions would be

`<name metadata="watch timekeeping pocket railway">Pocket Watch</name>`

`<name metadata="hotel">Bergenfield Hotel</name>`

`<name metadata="sweeney coal fuel">Sweeney Coal</name>`

`<name metadata="tunis cooper property museum">Tunis R. Cooper property</name>`

Except for the four string of code above the main coding would be done in a external DTD and I used the code `<!DOCTYPE photos SYSTEM "photos.dtd">` to port it over to the XML ( In which the examples are in ). Just in case there was any confusion.

Thank you for any help or input!

Answer (score 0):

> Do I simply input the code as `<!ATTLIST catalog type NMTOKEN #REQUIRED>`?

Yes.

> Or should I actually put a name for it?

Not sure what you mean by "name". You can't add anything else to that attlist without making it invalid. [An Nmtoken (name token) is any mixture of name characters](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Nmtoken).

> Would I simply make a similar code as shown above but with NMTOKENS in place?

Yes. This would allow the attribute to contain more than one NMTOKEN value.

> There are multiple code that have the similar element metadata. So would I just repeat the code until I have made a string for each metadata?

Do you mean there are multiple elements that have `metadata` attributes? If so then yes, you need to declare the attribute for each one of those elements.

Hopefully this answers your questions.